# How to calculate backpropagation offline

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I want to learn how to backpropagate neural net offline, so I came up with the example following:

[image]

and 1 stays for bias. Activation function in last layer is linear.

where

[image]

**My intuitive problem**

I want to calculate backprogation offline but I'm not sure how it should be done. I understand intuition behind online backprop where we calculate gradient observation by observation. But I don't have idea how it should work offline i.e. to calculate with all observations at once. Could you please give me a hint in which direction should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

So you say that you know how to do backpropagation on a single sample, but not on many samples at the same time, right? Then let's just assume that you have some loss function, e.g. the mean squared error. Then, for a single sample (x, label) your loss would be (y - label)^2. Since you said you know how to do backpropagation on a single sample, you should know that we now take the gradient of our loss with respect to out last node, y. This gradient should be 2 * (y - label). From there on, wo propagate the gradient through the whole network.

If we now have a batch of samples instead, we just use the loss function for the whole batch. Lets say out batch has two samples. Then our mean square error would just be the sum of the individual losses divided by the number of samples. Thus, the loss would be 1/2 * ((y_1 - label_1)^2 + ((y_2 - label_2)^2). And now we can just do the same as before: We take the gradient of our loss function with respect to our last node, y. It is important to realize, that both y_1 and y_2 in our loss are actually the output of our final node y, just for the different samples. This means, that the gradient is 1/2 * (2*(y_1 - label_1) + 2*(y_2 - label_2)). From here you have a single gradient value for the whole batch (if you plug in y_1, y_2, label_1, and label_2) and can propagate the gradient through the network as before.

As a summary: Instead of calculating the loss for a single sample, we now use a loss function that includes our whole batch (e.g. by just summing over all samples). This produces a single gradient, and we can proceed as before.